# Deleting a label in Tkinter when submitting new Entry

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to write a function through Tkinter with the following outcome:
User types in some input and submits
An outcome Label appears below the button as a result
When a new input is added in the Entry when the user submits the previous labels is destroyed and only the new result label appears.

I have searched several answers but I was unsuccessful in reaching my goal as with the current code below if a user submits several inputs there will be several labels appearing and when the reset button is clicked only the very last label is deleted while the previous labels still appear.

Here is what I have tried:

```
root = Tk()
root.title("Search")
root.geometry("400x400")
 
greeting= Label(root, text="Hi, Please insert input" )
greeting.pack()
 
search=[]
 
e = Entry(root, width=50)
e.pack(padx=50)
 
def myClick(event=None):
    global mySubmit
    global reply
    mySubmit=Label(root, text=results())
    search.append(e.get())
    print(search)
    e.delete(0,"end")
    mySubmit.pack()
 
def results():
    global result
    if e.get()=="":
        result = "Please Insert inquiry"
        return result
    else:
        result = "www.reply.com"
        return result
 
def reset():
    global mySubmit
    mySubmit.destroy()
    mySubmit = Label()
 
root.bind('<Return>', myClick)
 
myButton= Button(root, text="Submit", command=myClick)
myButton.pack()
bt2=Button(root,text='RESET',bg='lightblue',command=reset)
bt2.pack()
 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: A generally easier approach is to create the Label once at startup, then just change its text when needed - `mySubmit["text"] = result()` for example.

Comment: or `mySubmit.config(text=result())` is also an option to what @jasonharper said

Comment: also to be clear there only has to be one text at a time no matter how many inputs the user has made and when `reset()` is called text should disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `winfo_ismapped()` to know if that widget is already created or not. Pack it only when it is not already there.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Search")
root.geometry("400x400")
 
greeting= Label(root, text="Hi, Please insert input" )
greeting.pack()
 
search=[]
 
e = Entry(root, width=50)
e.pack(padx=50)

 
def myClick(event=None):
    global mySubmit
    global reply
    
    search.append(e.get())
    print(search)
    e.delete(0,"end")
    if(not mySubmit.winfo_ismapped()): #make a widget only if the mySubmit label is not mapped (created) till now
        mySubmit.pack()
 
def results():
    global result
    if e.get()=="":
        result = "Please Insert inquiry"
        return result
    else:
        result = "www.reply.com"
        return result

mySubmit=Label(root, text=results())    #declare it here outside the function scope

def reset():
    global mySubmit
    mySubmit.destroy()
    mySubmit = Label()
 
root.bind('<Return>', myClick)
 
myButton= Button(root, text="Submit", command=myClick)
myButton.pack()
bt2=Button(root,text='RESET',bg='lightblue',command=reset)
bt2.pack()
 
root.mainloop()
```